# Vertical align of text in divs

Tags: css

So I've got two divs next to each other and I'd like the text from the left one to be in one line with the first line from the second one.

```css
div {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Adress</div>
 <div class="right">Some street</br>1200-21 Los Angeles</div>
```

Comment: Can you be clear? You just need two divs in separate lines?

Comment: No, I want both divs in one line, but I don't want the text from the left one to be at the bottom of the div.

Comment: Then you can go with @emmanuel's answer

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property should help.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Adress</div>
<div class="right">Some street</br>1200-21 Los Angeles</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
div:first-child {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/afshin2740/z2zbb7d4/1/)